# How should standard errors for mixed effects model estimates be calculated?

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model

In particular, how should the standard errors of the fixed effects in a linear mixed effects model be calculated (in a frequentist sense)?

I have been lead to believe that the typical estimates (${\rm Var}(\hat\beta)=(X'VX)^{-1}$), such as those presented in Laird and Ware [1982] will give SE's that are underestimated in size because the estimated variance components are treated as though they are the true values.

I have noticed that the SE's produced by the `lme` and `summary` functions in the `nlme` package for R are not simply equal to the square root of the diagonals of the variance-covariance matrix given above. How are they calculated?

I am also under the impression that Bayesians use inverse gamma priors for the estimation of variance components. Do these give the same results (in the right setting) as `lme`?

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure what lme/nlme does, but I seem to remember them being asymptotic confidence intervals, in which case, they could be the (sqrt of) the diagonals of the inverse fisher information, since the estimates are MLEs.

Comment: @Macro, I shall check this out. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial thought was that, for ordinary linear regression, we just plug in our estimate of the residual variance, $\sigma^2$, as if it were the truth.

However, take a look at [McCulloch and Searle (2001)  Generalized, linear and mixed models, 1st edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470073713), Section 6.4b, "Sampling variance". They indicate that *you can't just plug in the estimates of the variance components*:

> Instead of dealing with the variance (matrix) of a vector $X \hat{\beta}$ we 
>   consider the simpler case of the scalar $l' \hat{\beta}$ for estimable $l'\beta$ (i.e., $l' = t'X$ for some $t'$).
>
> For known $V$,  we have from (6.21) that $\text{var}(l' \beta^0) = l'(X'V{-1}X)^- l$.  A replacement for this when $V$ is not known is to use $l'(X'\hat{V}^{-1}X)^- l$, which is an estimate of $\text{var}(l'\beta^0) = \text{var}[l' (X' V^{-1} X)^- X' V^{-1} y]$.  But it is *not* an estimate of $\text{var}(l'\hat{\beta}) = \text{var}[l' (X' \hat{V}^{-1} X)^- X' \hat{V}^{-1} y]$.  The latter requires taking account of the variability of $\hat{V}$ as well as that in $y$.  To deal with this, Kackar and Harville (1984, p. 854) observe that (in our notation) $l' \hat{\beta} - l' \beta$ can be expressed as the sum of two independent parts, $l' \hat{\beta} - l' \beta^0$ and $l'\beta^0 - l' \beta$.  This leads to $\text{var}(l' \hat{\beta})$ being expressed as a sum of two variances which we write as
>
> $$\text{var}(l'\hat{\beta}) = ... \approx l'(X' V^{-1} X)l + l' T \; l$$

They go on to explain $T$.

So this answers the first part of your question and indicates that your intuition was correct (and mine was wrong).